# Pipes don't work in loop with forks

Tags: c, pipe, fork

How it should work: parent creates a child, that executes first command and redirects the output to the pipe, then second child redirects standart input to that pipe.

My problem: when second child tries to read from the pipe, it waits forever 

(I really need a loop here, because in my actual program I will not know how many commands I will have, so it's just a simple version)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    int fd[2]; 

    pipe(fd);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            printf("\nloop %d\n", i);
            if (i == 0) {
                dup2(fd[1], 1);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
                printf("\nbefore exec %s\n", argv[1]);
                execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
            }
            else if(i == 1) {
                dup2(fd[0], 0);
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
                printf("\nbefore exec %s\n", argv[2]);
                execlp(argv[2], argv[2], NULL);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: If you check the return values of your function calls as you should do, then you will know where the failure occurs, if indeed there is any actual failure at all.

Comment: First child dies after "dup2(fd[1], 1)", but I don't understand why..

Comment: What is the return value from `dup2`?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the first child either fails at the `execlp()`, or that the exec'd program hangs or blocks, or indeed that the exec'd program runs to completion and terminates.  Note in particular that the output of its `printf()` will go into the pipe.  You could `fprintf()` to `stderr` to avoid that.

Comment: Again, however, if any of the function calls fails then you can know it from their return values.  For these particular functions you furthermore can determine the nature of the failure based on `errno`, and a convenient way to get feedback about that would be via the `perror()` function (which, by the way, sends its output to `stderr`, not `stdout`).

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the failure to check the return values of your function calls and to handle errors that may be indicated by those return values, your code looks pretty reasonable.  I do see two problems, however:

1. The most significant problem I see is that the main process keeps its own copies of the pipe ends open.  As long as there is at least one open file description referring to the write end of the pipe, in any process, end-of-file will not be signaled to the read end.  If the process running at the read end is one that reads its input to completion, such as `cat`, `grep`, or `sed`, then that process will wait forever for the write end to be closed, because the main process won't exit until that child terminates (because of the `wait()`).
2. The main process waits for each child immediately after forking it, and in particular, it waits for the first child before forking the second.  Pipes have finite buffers, and if the first child fills the pipe buffer before it finishes writing all its output, then it will block.  In that case, the main process will never launch the second child, which otherwise would have drained the pipe.

Overall, it is usually appropriate for a pipe to provide communication between two endpoints only.  In that usual case, it is important to launch both reader and writer without unnecessary delay, and to ensure that all handles on the pipe ends are closed, in all processes, except for one copy of the read end in one thread of one process, and one copy of the write end in a different thread or different process.  In a case such as yours, avoiding unnecessary delay includes not `wait()`ing for any child process until both (all) of the children have been launched.